# Zeppelin Cannot Import Numpy

Tags: pyspark, conda, apache-zeppelin

I use conda environment together with Zeppelin 0.7.3, Python 3.6, and Spark 2.2.1 (local mode). Pyspark interpreter is set to the absolute path of my python in conda env. Numpy is installed in the environment, and Zeppelin's config is correct. When I type `import numpy as np` directly in a notebook nothing goes wrong.

However my pyspark code is having problems seeing numpy. When I tried to train a random forest model it threw following error:

```
rfModel = rf.fit(transformedDataframe)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-8845198282152861593.py", line 360, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 19, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 64, in fit
    return self._fit(dataset)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 265, in _fit
    java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 262, in _fit_java
    return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o249.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 13.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 92, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 164, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 93, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 79, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 55, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 169, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 455, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pyspark.ml.base import Estimator, Model, Transformer
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pyspark.ml.param import Params
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1038)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2861)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2842)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2841)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2363)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.Classifier.getNumClasses(Classifier.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier.train(RandomForestClassifier.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier.train(RandomForestClassifier.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My code works smoothly if submitted via `spark-submit`. I exhausted SO but the only advice I can get is "install numpy", which is obviously not my solution.

Comment: Simply - Spark __workers__ don't use the same interpreter or `PYTHONPATH`. Make sure there are properly configured (`PYSPARK_PYTHON` for example).

Comment: @user8371915 I pointed Zeppelin interpreter property `zeppelin.pyspark.python` to my conda python. Is that the correct setting?

Comment: Also Spark runs in local[*] mode, so there is no real worker I guess?

Comment: "I pointed Zeppelin interpreter property zeppelin.pyspark.python to my conda python. Is that the correct setting?" - I am pretty sure it only used by the driver (notebook) not by the workers. "Also Spark runs in local[*] mode, so there is no real worker I guess?" - on the contrary. While `local[*]` keeps a single JVM, each worker thread still runs as a separate Python process.

Comment: @user8371915 thanks, but how to use different environments? Do I need to change `PYSPARK_PYTHON` every time? Can I specify it at run time?

Comment: try setting spark.pyspark.python to your conda python. And as you mentioned early, it only works for local mode. You need to install numpy on all nodes if you want it work in distributed mode. BTW, there's one PR that support virtualenv in pyspark, but not merged in spark yet, stay tuned. https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/13599/files

Answer (score 0):

Check your $PATH variable contains python path
And CONDA_NPY & CONDA_PREFIX are set